# is this possible to send parameters to binding events from xml views

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

I'm trying to use DataBinding in Android.
But i have a question in my mind.

I want to send edittext's text to binding functions inside xml.
I mean; When the login button is clicked, I want to get the current username and password from the xml IDs. Is it possible?

Here what I want:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(login_edt_username.text, login_edt_password.text)}"
```

My Current Usage:

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_login);
}

@Override
public void onLogin() {
    login(binding.loginEdtUserName.getText(),binding.loginEdtPassword.getText());
}
```

Xml:

```
<layout>

<data>

    <variable
        name="login"
        type="interfaces.login.LoginInterface" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.friends.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_edt_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_edt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_edt_user_name"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin()}"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_edt_password"
        android:text="SIGN IN" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn_register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> login.onRegister()}"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_btn_sign_in"
        android:text="REGISTER" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be solved using 2-way Databinding (available since version 2.1 of the Gradle Plugin).

**Alternative** 1:

Import `android.view.View` in your XML:

```
<data ...>
   <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

Then, you will be able to reference [*some*](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/) attributes of your Views directly in XML. In Lambda Expressions, like you're using, you can also use the Views like you would in Java.
Concretely:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(login_edt_username.getText().toString(), login_edt_password.getText().toString())}"
```

**Alternative** 2: Using a POJO.
Given a POJO modelling your credential information, such as

```
public class Credentials {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

, after declaring this model in your XML

```
<data>
  <variable
     name="login"
     type="interfaces.login.LoginInterface" />
  <variable
     name="credentials"
     type="models.login.Credentials" />
</data>
```

You could do:

```
   <!-- .... -->
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/login_edt_user_name"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       <!-- This binds the value of the Edittext to the Model. Note the equals sign! -->
       android:text="@={credentials.username}" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/login_edt_password"
       <!-- Same here -->
       android:text="@={credentials.password}" />

   <!-- ... -->
```

and finally, to fit your requirement

```
android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(credentials.username, credentials.password)}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your first alternative and it worked with small changing. First I import android.view.View to data, then I added this code to onClick : android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(loginEdtUserName.getText().toString(), loginEdtPassword.getText().toString())}" .

Comment: Why would you need to import `View`?

Comment: @tynn This is so you can reference the Elements that inherit from View, such as `Edittext`. This is probably needed for the Code Generation to work, which powers Databinding on Android. Check this [part of the databinding docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#layout_details)

Comment: Actually you don't need to import `View` here. Data bindings will create a variable of type `EditText` for you already. Using it is just the same as using a type returned by a function. You don't need to import it. You only need to import it if you use it directly like `View.GONE`. It should not do any harm, but is unnecessary. Also the variables of the views have CamelCase names like @b.erdi commented before.

Answer (score 2):

When you add an id to a view, this view is accessible by this id from the binding. This includes accessing it from within bindings set in the layout itself.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_edt_user_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_edt_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/login_edt_user_name"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(loginEdtUserName.getText(), loginEdtPassword.getText())}"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_edt_password"
    android:text="SIGN IN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some conflict when +id uses the "login_edt_user_name" format. Make sure identifiers use camelCase so they can be properly accessed:

Correct:

`android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(loginEdtUserName.getText(), loginEdtPassword.getText())}"`

Wrong:

`android:onClick="@{() -> login.onLogin(login_edt_user_name.getText(), login_edt_password.getText())}"`